# Awk to convert TSV table into grid table

Tags: awk, text-formatting, table

I want to convert a text table with tab as delimiter
(i.e., basically a TSV file)
to a grid table with lines on all borders (inside and outside)
and text wrapping.

The below is the input

```
   TrackId         peerId                                             Cause                                     Count
ESS_RSM         pra4.pra.pnc100.tpp240.6pppsetwork.prg             40009 Response is not received from server   1401
ESS_RSM         pra5.pra.pnc100.tpp240.6pppsetwork.prg             40009 Response is not received from server   1398
ESS_RSM         pra3.pra.pnc100.tpp240.6pppsetwork.prg             40009 Response is not received from server   1347
ESS_RSM         pra1.pra.pnc100.tpp240.6pppsetwork.prg             40009 Response is not received from server   1412
ESS_RSM         pra2.pra.pnc100.tpp240.6pppsetwork.prg             40009 Response is not received from server   1355
ESS_RSM         pra6.pra.pnc100.tpp240.6pppsetwork.prg             40009 Response is not received from server   1416
```

The large expanses of whitespace are tabs;
the whitespace in "Response is not received from server" is spaces. 
The output should be as below:

```
 ┌────────┬────────────────────────────────────────┬────────────────────────────┬────────┐
 │TrackId │ peerId                                 │ Cause                      │ Count  │
 ├────────┼────────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────┼────────┤
 │ESS_RSM │ pra4.pra.pnc100.tpp240.6pppsetwork.prg │ 40009 Response is not      │  1,401 │
 │        │                                        │ received from server       │        │
 ├────────┼────────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────┼────────┤
 │ESS_RSM │ pra5.pra.pnc100.tpp240.6pppsetwork.prg │ 40009 Response is not      │  1,398 │
 │        │                                        │ received from server       │        │
 ├────────┼────────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────┼────────┤
 │ESS_RSM │ pra3.pra.pnc100.tpp240.6pppsetwork.prg │ 40009 Response is not      │  1,347 │
 │        │                                        │ received from server       │        │
 ├────────┼────────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────┼────────┤
 │ESS_RSM │ pra1.pra.pnc100.tpp240.6pppsetwork.prg │ 40009 Response is not      │  1,412 │
 │        │                                        │ received from server       │        │
 ├────────┼────────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────┼────────┤
 │ESS_RSM │ pra2.pra.pnc100.tpp240.6pppsetwork.prg │ 40009 Response is not      │  1,355 │
 │        │                                        │ received from server       │        │
 ├────────┼────────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────┼────────┤
 │ESS_RSM │ pra6.pra.pnc100.tpp240.6pppsetwork.prg │ 40009 Response is not      │  1,416 │
 │        │                                        │ received from server       │        │
 └────────┴────────────────────────────────────────┴────────────────────────────┴────────┘
```

or maybe

```
TrackId │ peerId                         │ Cause                                │ Count   │
────────┼────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────┼─────────┤
        │ pra4.pra.pnc100.tpp240.6pppset │ 40009 Response is not received from  │         │
ESS_RSM │ work.prg                       │ server                               │   1,401 │
────────┼────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────┼─────────┤
        │ pra5.pra.pnc100.tpp240.6pppset │ 40009 Response is not received from  │         │
ESS_RSM │ work.prg                       │ server                               │   1,398 │
────────┼────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────┼─────────┤
        │ pra3.pra.pnc100.tpp240.6pppset │ 40009 Response is not received from  │         │
ESS_RSM │ work.prg                       │ server                               │   1,347 │
────────┼────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────┼─────────┤
        │ pra1.pra.pnc100.tpp240.6pppset │ 40009 Response is not received from  │         │
ESS_RSM │ work.prg                       │ server                               │   1,412 │
────────┼────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────┼─────────┤
        │ pra2.pra.pnc100.tpp240.6pppset │ 40009 Response is not received from  │         │
ESS_RSM │ work.prg                       │ server                               │   1,355 │
────────┼────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────┼─────────┤
        │ pra6.pra.pnc100.tpp240.6pppset │ 40009 Response is not received from  │         │
ESS_RSM │ work.prg                       │ server                               │   1,416 │
────────┴────────────────────────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────┴─────────┘
```

I tried the below code, but the output is not what I want.

```
awk '{print "<table>"} {print "<tr>"; for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) print "|" $i "|";print "|"} END {PRINT "|"}' file
```

Comment: Please convert your image into text.

Comment: Actually the text with table when copied above only text displayed not table format..

Comment: What effect would you expect "<table>" to have on awk? Are you expecting to output XML or HTML this way, and have that convert it to table format?

Comment: The data is not space delimited, because the 'Cause' column then constitutes seven fields.

Comment: The table need to have four column which originally seperated by \t tab. While the cause column data seperated by space not tab. So, Output should look like as picture shown above. Is it possible to get such Output. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Or each column atleast seperated by pipe "|".

Comment: It's very unclear what you want output. The image you posted looks like you want tabular output with cells in each row separated by `|`, but then the code you posted shows you trying to print HTML. Please [edit] your question to simply show, as text, what output you expect given the input you posted.

Comment: Replacing `TAB` by `|` is trivial. How would that be an alternative to your initial requirement? `sed -e 's+\t+|+g' 604776.data`

Comment: You didn't answer [my question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/604776/awk-to-convert-tsv-table-into-grid-table#comment1128698_604776) but if you just want to wrap text within fields to produce tabular output of specific width then see https://stackoverflow.com/a/55209032/1745001 - just do that for each field you need to wrap and then massage the output. If you post a clear question then we can help you more.

Comment: Thanks Ed Morton, Will try as advised and let you know

Comment: Just post a question with concise, testable sample input and expected output **in text**, not as pictures, and someone will be able to help you. Whatever you're trying to do isn't going to be difficult, we just don't know **exactly** what it is you're trying to do and so it's hard to help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using some ancient Unix utilities,

```
#!/bin/sh
{
        printf '%s\n' '' .TS 'allbox;LLLL,LLLR.'
        awk -v sq="'" '
            BEGIN { FS = OFS = "\t"; fmt = "%" sq "d" }
            NR==1 { print }
            NR>1  {
                        print $1, "T{"
                        print          $2
                        print             "T}", "T{"
                        print                        $3
                        print                           "T}", sprintf(fmt, $4)
                  }
            ' "$@"
        printf '%s\n' .TE '.pl 0'
} | tbl | nroff 2> /dev/null
```

Explanation:

- `nroff` is the ancient Unix text processor. 
  It will, for example, take

  ```
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
  sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
  Ut enim ad minim veniam,
  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi
  ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit
  in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
  Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident,
  sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  ```

  as input, and produce

  ```
  Lorem  ipsum  dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
  eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna  aliqua.   Ut
  enim  ad  minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
  nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.  Duis aute  irure  dolor
  in  reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat
  nulla pariatur.  Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non  proident,
  sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  ```

  as output.
- `tbl` is a front-end to `nroff` to support — you guessed it —
  the generation of tables.
- `.TS` is “table start”.
- `allbox` is fairly obvious: draw a box around every cell.
- `LLLL` means all cells in the first row are left-justified;
  `LLLR` means that the fourth cell is right-justified
  for all subsequent rows. 
  I guess this is what you want from looking at your sample output.
- `-v sq="'"` creates a variable called `sq`
  whose value is a single quote. 
  This is one of the ways of using a single quote in an awk program,
  and is suggested in [The GNU Awk User’s Guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Quoting.html).
- Set `FS` to tab because the input is TSV. 
  Set `OFS` to tab because that’s what `tbl` expects (by default).
- `fmt = "%" sq "d"` sets `fmt` to `%'d`,
  which can be used with `[s]printf`
  to output an integer with thousands separators.
  (I assume that you want this, since you showed it.)
- Pass the first line (the headers) through unmodified.
- For all other rows (data),
  use the `T{` and `T}` tokens to make `$2` and `$3`
  subject to text wrapping. 
  (I assume that you want this for the second and third columns only,
  since the first and fourth columns contain only short strings.) 
  Print the value of `$4` with comma(s) inserted every three digits.
- `.TE` is “table end”.
- `.pl` is page length. 
  This is something of a kludge. 
  By default, `nroff` will pad its output with blank lines
  to get the overall output to be a multiple of 66 lines. 
  By setting the page length to zero, we suppress that.
- Output from the above (`printf`, `awk` and `printf`)
  gets piped into `tbl` and `nroff`.
- I had a lot of problems with error messages appearing,
  even though the standard output was reasonable,
  so I sent stderr to the bitbucket. 
  If you get weird results, the first thing you should do
  is get rid of the stderr redirection and look at the error messages
  (although they might not be very helpful).

Instructions:

- Put the above code into a file. 
  For example, call it `gman`.
- Do

  ```
  $ chmod +x gman
  ```

  to make it executable.
- If your data are in a file (for example, called `shap`), do

  ```
  $ ./gman shap
  ```

  You will probably want to redirect the output to a file:

  ```
  $ ./gman shap > grid_table
  ```

> - If you get all your data in the first column,
>   that means that your input file doesn’t really have tabs in it
>   (just spaces).
>   Edit it to replace the whitespace (spaces) with tabs.

- If your data are generated/produced by some other program,
  for example, a database query, you can do

  ```
  $ db_query > tmp
  $ ./gman tmp
  ```

  (and then optionally `rm tmp`, if you don’t need it for anything else),
  or simply

  ```
  $ db_query | ./gman
  ```
- If you move (or copy) the `gman` file
  to a directory that’s in your search path,
  you’ll be able to run it simply by typing `gman` (without the **`./`**). 
  There is a *lot* of documentation on this; it’s easy to find if you search.

For example, for the input shown in the question, I get

```
┌───────────┬─────────────────────────────────┬───────────────┬───────┐
│   TrackId │ peerId                          │ Cause         │ Count │
├───────────┼─────────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────┤
│ESS_RSM    │ pra4.pra.pnc100.tpp240.6pppset‐ │ 40009     Re‐ │ 1,401 │
│           │ work.prg                        │ sponse is not │       │
│           │                                 │ received from │       │
│           │                                 │ server        │       │
├───────────┼─────────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────┤
│ESS_RSM    │ pra5.pra.pnc100.tpp240.6pppset‐ │ 40009     Re‐ │ 1,398 │
│           │ work.prg                        │ sponse is not │       │
│           │                                 │ received from │       │
│           │                                 │ server        │       │
├───────────┼─────────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────┤
│ESS_RSM    │ pra3.pra.pnc100.tpp240.6pppset‐ │ 40009     Re‐ │ 1,347 │
│           │ work.prg                        │ sponse is not │       │
│           │                                 │ received from │       │
│           │                                 │ server        │       │
├───────────┼─────────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────┤
│ESS_RSM    │ pra1.pra.pnc100.tpp240.6pppset‐ │ 40009     Re‐ │ 1,412 │
│           │ work.prg                        │ sponse is not │       │
│           │                                 │ received from │       │
│           │                                 │ server        │       │
├───────────┼─────────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────┤
│ESS_RSM    │ pra2.pra.pnc100.tpp240.6pppset‐ │ 40009     Re‐ │ 1,355 │
│           │ work.prg                        │ sponse is not │       │
│           │                                 │ received from │       │
│           │                                 │ server        │       │
├───────────┼─────────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────┤
│ESS_RSM    │ pra6.pra.pnc100.tpp240.6pppset‐ │ 40009     Re‐ │ 1,416 │
│           │ work.prg                        │ sponse is not │       │
│           │                                 │ received from │       │
│           │                                 │ server        │       │
└───────────┴─────────────────────────────────┴───────────────┴───────┘
```

as output. 
There are tricks for making columns (e.g., the third one) wider;
let me know what you want to know.

Warning: When you run this, `tbl` and `nroff` will

1. read all the data,
2. store it in memory and/or a temporary file,
3. compute the column widths, and then
4. output all the data.

If you have *a **lot*** of data,
you may overflow the limits of the temporary storage,
and the command will fail. 
You might be able to get usable results
by breaking the input into smaller files.

Warning: if your file contains `T{` or `T}`,
or values that begin with a period (**`.`**) or a single quote (**`'`**),
you may get weird results.

Comment: Pure absolute genius (with a nostalgia icing)! Why contemplate HTML when nroff (and her posh cousin troff) is lurking in the cellar?

Comment: Nice to know that there are some people here whose memory goes back as far as mine!     :-)    ⁠

Comment: I still have the Bell System Technical Journal  (Aug 1978) that was dedicated to Unix (and produced by troff), with the chapter on "Document Preparation".

Comment: Really its nice to see your generated table. But how to execute this code .

Comment: @shanulqureshi copy/paste the provided code into your terminal window then hit "Enter". That is all you have to do. If you're having any trouble with that then provide some information on what's going wrong (error messages, etc.).

Comment: Dear Morton.. Where i have to specify input file in this code.

Comment: Replace `"$@"` with a file name. The code as written was intended to be stored in a file and executed as a shell script.

Comment: I tried it table formed but all columns of input file displayed only in first column.. Column 2,3,4 are empty

Comment: In one of my server this tbl from this code showing bash command not found"-bash: tbl: command not found"

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{$1=$1"|";$2=$2"|";$NF="|"$NF}1' input.txt | awk -F\| 'BEGIN{print "<table border=1>"}{gsub("\\|","</td><td>");print"<tr><td>"$0"</td></tr>"}END{print "</table>"}' > output.html
```

first awk is used to seperate the values by |

second awk is used to format the values to HTML table

Comment: What's the relevance of HTML to the question please?

Comment: The hard part of this is to equalise the column widths and decide which wide columns to wrap, and to examine the fields in each column and figure which are numeric, so we can right justify and add thousands separators. That means reading the whole file before we know how to format the first line. Mark-up languages tend to have pretty-print built-in. In Linux, I would import into LibreOfice Calc and send the result to PDF.

Comment: I believe I wrote a utility similar to this requirement for a client, around eight years ago. Seems to me it was around 150 lines of code, and did not do field folding or comma insertion. It also held all the data in memory arrays while it found out maximum field sizes. What would be your maximum data volume?