# awk liner to format input data in desired output

Tags: awk

Here is the input file.

```
    QSUM HEADER                          STOCK   DATE    TIME
206  CC-USER REJECT SENT             TNPPP   200322  104914600

TI         JPS        TNN        LTNN       PP         JP
                      8          6          0          1

AA         NS                                          CPOODE
4          899599991119

TYPE       AI
12         18

QSUM HEADER                          STOCK   DATE    TIME
206  CC-USER REJECT SENT             TNPPP   200322  115844000

TI         JPS        TNN        LTNN       PP         JP
                      8          6          0          1

AA         NS                                          CPOODE
4          899599991555

TYPE       AI
12         18
QSUM HEADER                          STOCK   DATE    TIME
103  SUITE FAIL, SUBTRACT FAILURE   TPNRM   200318  031124100

TI         PNC        TNN        PP         JP         AA
2          1499       177        123        1          4

NS                                          FLAG       
999999999999                                ORIGIN

TI         CPO


QSUM HEADER                          STOCK   DATE    TIME
103  SUITE FAIL, SUBTRACT FAILURE   TPNRM   200318  031124200

TI         PNC        TNN        PP         JP         AA
2          1499       177        123        1          4

NS                                          FLAG       
999999999999                                ORIGIN

TI         CPO
```

I need output as below

```
    QSUM HEADER                          STOCK   DATE    TIME       TI     PNC       JPS        TNN        LTNN       PP         JP AA         NS                     FLAG                     OPCODE TYPE       AI TI CPO
206  CC-USER REJECT SENT             TNPPP   200322  104914600                               8          6          0          1 4          899599991119                                       12         18
206  CC-USER REJECT SENT             TNPPP   200322  115844000                               8          6          0          1 4          899599991555                                       12         18
103  SUITE FAIL, SUBTRACT FAILURE   TPNRM   200318  031124100    2     1499                 177                   123         1 4          999999999999          ORIGIN
103  SUITE FAIL, SUBTRACT FAILURE   TPNRM   200318  031124200    2     1499                 177                   123         1 4          999999999999          ORIGIN
```

I tried sample awk liner as below

```
    awk 'BEGIN{print ("QSUM HEADER                          STOCK   DATE    TIME       TI     PNC       JPS        TNN        LTNN       PP         JP AA         NS                     FLAG                     OPCODE TYPE       AI TI CPO")}

/^[0-9]/{print a["o"] " " a["p"] " " a["q"]
              ;delete a}

             /^[0-9]/{a["o"]=$0
              next}
             /TNN/{getline
                    a["p"]=$0
                      next}
              /NS/{getline
                   a["q"]=$0
                   next}
                   END
                {print a["o"] " " a["p"] " " a["q"];}'
```

for each header type , I need match pattern and then array next line. Any other good alternative to achieve this Output.. This code works for me but issue here is as many as header the code getting longer.

Comment: Are al of the spaces in your input and output blank chars or are some of them tab chars? If some are tabs, edit your question to indicate which ones (e.g. do `cat -t file` and include the output) or, even better, replace them with some char we can see, e.g. a `;` - you can always convert `;` to tab in the code later for use on your real input. That is not a safe or appropriate use of `getline` btw, see http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline.

Comment: It seems all are spaces not tab

Comment: (1) Multiple people have encouraged you to make your code more readable. Ed Morton gave you an example [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/604899/80216); I gave you an example [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/604776/80216#604865). Patterns (`BEGIN`, `END`, `NR==1` and `NR>1`, etc.) are lined up. Statements that go together are lined up. ``{`` and ``}`` have spaces before and after them. If your code is hard to read, people will not help you. (2) I asked you (on your previous question) to ***explain*** what you want to accomplish.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  Yes, showing the result you want is good, but you should do that *in addition* to explaining the problem, not instead of it. (3) Is the alignment of your data really as messy as you show it? For example, `STOCK`, `DATE` and `TIME` line up with `TNPPP`, `200322` and `115844000` in the second data set, but not the first, third or fourth. This makes your question hard to understand. If the values really are not lined up, you should mention that — in your explanation.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (4) Your output data is 218 characters wide. That makes it very hard to read and understand.  (5) The fact that each data set (`206` and `103`) appears twice adds to the confusion.  (6) Why on earth are you using `"o"`, `"p"` and `"q"` as indices (instead of, say, `1`, `2` and `3`)?  (7) I noticed that the input contains `CPOODE` and the output contains `OPCODE`, in roughly the same position. Is `CPOODE` a typo for `OPCODE` (or vice versa)?  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (8) I stared at your question, and stared at it, and stared it, and finally I thought that maybe — just maybe — I understood it.  Then my head exploded.  (9) Do you understand your question, yourself?  Given the input, would you be able to produce the output manually?  ***EXPLAIN!*** It looks like it’s much more complicated than your code or your (minimal) description would suggest. … … … I’m sorry if English is not your primary language, but please try. … … … … … … … … … (10) By the way, why do you call it an “awk liner”?

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' My guess is that it clearly takes up more than one line, so it’s not a “one-liner”...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With GNU awk for `FPAT` and `FIELDWIDTHS` (and then taking advantage of gawks `\s/\S` shorthand for `[[:space:]]/[^[:space:]]`):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS="\t" }

/^\s*$/ { next }        # skip blank lines

/^\s*QSUM\s/ {          # start of a new record
    numRecs++
    lineNr = 0
}

{
    if ( (++lineNr) % 2 == 1 ) {
        # tags line so find every tag and field width
        FPAT = "\\S+\\s*"
        $0 = $0
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
            tag = $i
            fw = (i>1 ? fw " " : "") (i<NF ? length(tag) : "*")
            gsub(/^\s+|\s+$/,"",tag)
            if ( !(tag in tagNames2nrs) ) {
                tagNrs2names[++numTags] = tag
                tagNames2nrs[tag] = numTags
            }
            fldNr2tagNr[i] = tagNames2nrs[tag]
        }
        FPAT = ""
    }
    else {
        # vals line so use the field widths found for tags
        FIELDWIDTHS = fw
        $0 = $0
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
            val = $i
            gsub(/^\s+|\s+$/,"",val)
            tagNr = fldNr2tagNr[i]
            vals[numRecs,tagNr] = val
        }
        FIELDWIDTHS = ""
    }
}

END {
    for (tagNr=1; tagNr<=numTags; tagNr++) {
        tag = tagNrs2names[tagNr]
        printf "%s%s", tag, (tagNr<numTags ? OFS : ORS)
    }

    for (recNr=1; recNr<=numRecs; recNr++) {
        for (tagNr=1; tagNr<=numTags; tagNr++) {
            val = vals[recNr,tagNr]
            printf "%s%s", val, (tagNr<numTags ? OFS : ORS)
        }
    }
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file | column -s$'\t' -t
QSUM  HEADER                        STOCK  DATE    TIME       TI  JPS  TNN  LTNN  PP   JP  AA  NS            CPOODE  TYPE  AI  PNC   FLAG    CPO
206   CC-USER REJECT SENT           TNPPP  200322  104914600           8    6     0    1   4   899599991119          12    18
206   CC-USER REJECT SENT           TNPPP  200322  115844000           8    6     0    1   4   899599991555          12    18
103   SUITE FAIL, SUBTRACT FAILURE  TPNRM  200318  031124100  2        177        123  1   4   999999999999                    1499  ORIGIN
103   SUITE FAIL, SUBTRACT FAILURE  TPNRM  200318  031124200  2        177        123  1   4   999999999999                    1499  ORIGIN
```

Since every pair of lines has different fields with some being empty, we have to rely on fixed with fields to read the data but we don't know how many fields and what width they are until we try to read them. So, that script uses FPAT to find every tag (aka name aka header aka title) on each tags line:

```
TI         JPS        TNN        LTNN       PP         JP
```

to determine the width of each field (includes the tag name and following blanks) and then can use FIELDWIDTHS to read the values from the subsequent values line:

```
                      8          6          0          1
```

as fixed width fields even if any of the fields is empty.

I'm not going to comment it or otherwise generally explain it more than that as IMHO the code is pretty clear you're asking a LOT of text manipulation questions and so it's time to learn a bit about awk from reading some code, looking up the man page, adding `print` statements where you need to see what values variables have, etc. If after all of that you have specific questions then of course please do feel free to ask.

The above was run against this input file which is the same as the one in your question but with the inconsistent alignment problems with the QSUM, STOCK, DATA, and TIME headers fixed because I don't believe your real input could be that messy (but if it is it'd be an easy tweak to handle it):

```
$ cat file

QSUM HEADER                          STOCK   DATE    TIME
206  CC-USER REJECT SENT             TNPPP   200322  104914600

TI         JPS        TNN        LTNN       PP         JP
                      8          6          0          1

AA         NS                                          CPOODE
4          899599991119

TYPE       AI
12         18

QSUM HEADER                          STOCK   DATE    TIME
206  CC-USER REJECT SENT             TNPPP   200322  115844000

TI         JPS        TNN        LTNN       PP         JP
                      8          6          0          1

AA         NS                                          CPOODE
4          899599991555

TYPE       AI
12         18
QSUM HEADER                         STOCK   DATE    TIME
103  SUITE FAIL, SUBTRACT FAILURE   TPNRM   200318  031124100

TI         PNC        TNN        PP         JP         AA
2          1499       177        123        1          4

NS                                          FLAG
999999999999                                ORIGIN

TI         CPO


QSUM HEADER                         STOCK   DATE    TIME
103  SUITE FAIL, SUBTRACT FAILURE   TPNRM   200318  031124200

TI         PNC        TNN        PP         JP         AA
2          1499       177        123        1          4

NS                                          FLAG
999999999999                                ORIGIN

TI         CPO
```

Comment: Excellent and inventive solution. Mine came out about 40% bigger (although it does not keep everything in memory until the end), but I did go out for a very pleasant lunch halfway through. I do have a weakness for code that finds out about the data itself, instead of relying on being told every little detail. 10/10 for this!

Comment: @Paul_Pedant Thanks! Unfortunately it has to keep everything in memory till the end or do a 2-pass approach since the input records don't all have the same fields populated (e.g. `JPS`, `LTMN`, `FLAG`, and `CPOODE`) but you need every field populated for every output record so you can't print the first record until you've read the last record since the last record might have some field that wasn't present in the first record.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ed Morton. Really appreciated

Comment: @EdMorton Absolutely understand the reasons, but OP didn't mention file size as a problem so assume we can store it all. I got all the titles and field widths upfront by parsing the sample output header (including the repeated TI). I unfolded the multiline data in pairs, which gave me big issues with the ragged endings of the folded lines. FPAT was instructive for me, too: especially alternating with FIELDWIDTHS.

Comment: @EdMorton , In one of my server while executing got below error. :--> awk: /local/Qsum_vrf/QSUMFRMT.awk:29: (FILENAME=QSUM_202_ALLNODE FNR=3) fatal: invalid FIELDWIDTHS value, near `*'

Comment: Then you're using an old version of gawk that didn't support `*` to mean "whatever's left" as the final field width. Upgrade your awk version or, if you can't do that, then change `*` to `999` or some other large number in the script.

Comment: @EdMorton My awk [GNU Awk 4.1.3, API: 1.1 (GNU MPFR 3.1.4, GNU MP 6.1.0)] throws the same, and your fix works. I'm still on a learning trip with your code. The output formatting threw me. You made it a TAB-separated file for further processing. I assumed it was a final report, and fully spaced the columns. As always, a spec isn't a spec until the user has had the product for four months.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant that's 5 years old, we''re on gawk 5.1.0 now. Looks like it's been 3 years since I asked for that gawk enhancement (https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gawk/2017-05/msg00042.html) so it's been around for a while and I'd guess it went into gawk 4.2.0. Right, the **awk** output is tab-separated but then the subsequent pipe to `column` I show produces the tabular report the OP wanted (or that awk output could be imported it into Excel or whatever else they want to do with it).

Comment: @EdMorton I have an ancient Laptop so I'm sticking to the oldest supported distro: Linux Mint 18.1 'Serena'. Sorry, I forgot that `| column` was part of the solution. I guess that also needs a two-pass at the data.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant that's actually a good point I hadn't considered - that piping to `column` is adding yet another 2 passes of the data. Hopefully it's done efficiently!

Comment: @EdMorton We can simulate `column` in awk in about 10 lines, because we already have everything we need in memory. I'm still exploring FPAT and its friend patsplit() -- didn't realise they can split data with (effectively) a null separator.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant yeah, I know, I'd just rather not reimplement the wheel if I don't have to. `patsplit` is actually a function I rarely, if ever, use since it's really just `split()` with the 2nd and 4th args swapped.

Answer (score 1):

I would turn this problem on its head. Start in the BEGIN section by making an array of the array columns you want as **output**, in order. The column width and the text (to start with):

```
BEGIN {
    defCol[ 1] = "  5 QSUM";
    defCol[ 2] = " 28 HEADER";
    ...
    defCol[19] = "  6 CPO";
}
```

Validate that by writing a function that just prints the header. You might iterate through defCol like:

```
printf ("%.*s", 0 + defCol[j], substr (defCol[j], 5);
```

Then write a function that collects an array of input lines between one QSUM input and the next, omitting blank lines. Lines with only caps and whitespace are titles, lines with anything else are data with the fields lined up to the previous title line. (I assume the misalignment of the top line in both input and output is a typo).

For each group, you match the title to the column name to figure which pigeon-hole the data item belongs in (as an array indexed the same as defCol, naturally). You can then print the detail line using the defCol indexes to sequence the fields, and the defCol width in a printf formatter.

That sounds complex, but it is flexible (it looks like you will have other similar problems in the near future), and systematic. You can also flag up things like titles you never saw before, fields too long for the report, and so on.

**More detailed functional description:**

First you need a condition that detects when you have completed one input group -- that used to be a "control break". That would happen on a line that contained "QSUM HEADER" or similar, with some pattern to allow varying spacing. You also don't want that to happen the first time (because you have not had a group yet), and you need it to also happen in the END condition (becasue the last group won't have a header to trigger it).

The rest of the input can be used to append all the header parts into one long string, and all the data parts into another long string, and ignore all the blank lines.

To output a group, you work through the header string looking for the positions of the data titles, and pick out the fields in the corresponding places in the data string, using the match() and substr() functions. You store each data item in an array using the same indexes as the header items.

Then you can output the data fields just like you did the header fixed texts.

That all sounds baffling, but it is reasonably straight-forward. I can't write the code right now, but I can probably post a framework later today.

**Actually, the input (as posted) is probably unparseable with any reliability, due to variability in spacing.**

For example, the values under STOCK, DATE and TIME don't align with the values consistently. We can't just count fields because the HEADER has spaces. We either fall back on two or more spaces as a separator, or some "close enough" field alignment. And this is just a 40-line sample: other hazards lie ahead.

Comment: Dear Paul, In your description header part is clear. But how to get data for each header type in corresponding rows. As I just want to print header for all data once in output as header and rest below are the data corresponding to that header.